# How to fast render list on Calendar with list 1000 elements and more

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have got one list with 5 sort of items:

### Kontrakt | Pracownik | Dzien | ID | Procenty

And When i Have 1000 elements its render me very slow on calendar. About 5-6 secounds. How can I do it fdaster and analyse them. Can I put the indexer on column ?

I have got that code to render on Calendar:

```
  protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
        SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPListItemCollection listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].Items;

            // Gdy nie ma zaznaczonej osoby to wtedy wyświetlamy wszystkie daty urlopów

            int index;

            if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "<-- Wszystcy pracownicy -->" || DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "")
            {

                foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
                {

                    if (e.Day.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Dzien"]).ToShortDateString())
                    {
                        e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0000");
                        e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                    }

                }
            }
            else

            // Renderowanie urlopu dla pojedyńczej zaznaczonej osobie
            {
                foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
                {
                    index = olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Pracownik"].ToString().IndexOf("#");

                    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Pracownik"].ToString().Substring(index + 1))
                    {
                        if (e.Day.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Dzien"]).ToShortDateString())
                        {
                            e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#F5BCA9");
                            e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                            e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:blue; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Kontrakt"].ToString() + "</p><p style='color:#5D198E;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3) + "</p>")));
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            SPWeb witryna1 = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPListItemCollection listaDniSwiatecznych = witryna1.Lists["DR2013 Święta"].Items;

            foreach (SPListItem olistaDniSwiatecznych in listaDniSwiatecznych)
            {
                // Wyświetlenie na kalendarzu weekendów
                if (e.Day.Date.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday" || e.Day.Date.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
                {
                    e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF9900");
                    e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                }

                // Wyświetlenie na kalendarzu dni świątecznych
                if (e.Day.Date.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(olistaDniSwiatecznych["Data"]).ToShortDateString())
                {
                    e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFF00");
                    e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:red; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniSwiatecznych["Data"].ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "</p>")));
                }

            }
    } // Koniec protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) to query your data instead of looping through all of it.

I'd recommend that you watch the videos at mssharepointdeveloper.com before starting to develop for SharePoint. Module 4 "Accessing SharePoint 2010 data and objects with server-side APIs" will give you some information about how to access data.

Comment: Thanks, for fast replay :)
But i must use a calm ?

Comment: And with Calm Queryes will be fasters ? Than this ?

Comment: Yes you should use CAML and unless you need to render all of the data it'll be faster. Currently you're doing something similar to an SQL query like `SELECT * FROM list` where with the right CAML it'll be like `SELECT Kontract, Procenty FROM list WHERE Dzien=selecteddate AND Pracownik=selecteditem`

Comment: Thanks :) And meyby Linq will be bether to do this than calm ? I use to Calm  U2U CALM Query Buldier, but if Linq is good enough like Calm I will prefer beter learn Linq

Comment: In most cases LINQ will generate fine CAML, but sometimes it'll create something as bad as the `SELECT * from list`.

Comment: I see thanks :) U2U CALM QUERY Buldier is good program in Your opinion to build Querrys in CALM ? Maybe same program's are better ?

Comment: U2U CAML Query Builder is an excellent tool to use

Comment: But how to use it? Are You know sny tutorial ? :)

Comment: Is this CALM Query fast Enough ? `<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name='Dzien' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>[Today+11Day(s)]</Value>
         </Lt>
         <Gt>
            <FieldRef Name='Dzien' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>[Today-11Day(s)]</Value>
         </Gt>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>`

Comment: No!!! First off it's wrong as it'll only work if all days in your calendar is within 11 days of today. Second your query should be narrow enough to eliminate all if statements inside your foreach loops. But let that discusion continue in your new question

Comment: Ok I made two Questions. One with CAML, and one with Linq

Comment: And how I can do a CAML query with Data Start, and Data End and getting a Range from Data Start to Data End ?